# Open file to read from web form

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a project where I have to upload a file from file storage (via web form) to MongoDB. In order to achieve this, I need to open the file in "rb" mode, then encode the file and finally upload to MongoDb. I am stuck when opening the file "rb" mode.

```
    if form.validate():
        for inFile in request.files.getlist("file"):

            connection = pymongo.MongoClient()
            db = connection.test
            uploads = db.uploads

            with open(inFile, "rb") as fin:
                f = fin.read()
                encoded = Binary(f,0)

                try:
                    uploads.insert({"binFile": encoded})
                    check = True
                except Exception as e:
                    self.errorList.append("Document upload is unsuccessful"+e)
                    check = False
```

The above code is throwing `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FileStorage found` in the `open` step, i.e. this line:

```
with open(inFile, "rb") as fin:
```

Is there a way I can change my code to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileStorage` object is already file-like so you can use as a file. You don't need to use `open` on it, just call `inFile.read()`.

If this doesn't work for you for some reason, you can save the file to disk first using `inFile.save()` and open it from there.

---

Reference: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage

Comment: @PRaju I'd appreciate an upvote if you're not too busy. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry dkasak. I did try to give an upvote but since I don't have atleast 15 reputations, the system is not showing upvotes from me.

Comment: Right, no worries. :)